# np.timedelta64 does not accept np.int64

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, types, casting

Why does np.timedelta64 does not accept numpy integers such as np.int64?

```
np.timedelta64(np.int64(2),'h')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-fd40c0d8eac0> in <module>()
----> 1 np.timedelta64(np.int64(2),'h')

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy timedelta
```

Comment: i also submitted an issue on github: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7462